# tkinter textbox align image

Tags: textbox, tkinter

I've got an image (which has the same height as 4 lines of text) in a text box, and I want it to go beside 4 lines of text. I'll insert it after the 2nd line, and I end up with the 1st line, followed by empty lines, followed by the 2nd line with the image beside it, more empty lines, and then the 3rd line. Is there a way of getting the Ideal setup?

```
          -----------------            -----------------
          |Line 1 |       |            |Line 1 |       |
    Ideal |Line 2 | Image | what I get |Blank  |       |
          |Line 3 |       |            |Line 2 | Image |
          |Line 4 |       |            |Blank  |       |
          -----------------            |Line 3 |       |
                                       |Line 4 |       |
                                       -----------------
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
textbox.insert(END, 'Line 1\n')
textbox.insert(END, 'Line 2')
self.img = PhotoImage(file='arrow.gif')
textbox.image_create(INSERT, image=self.img)
textbox.insert(END, '\n')
textbox.insert(END, 'Line 3\n')
textbox.insert(END, 'Line 4\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the Text widget as a grid where you can "span" more than one row/line, but works with lines of text, so your embedded image should belong to multiple lines to be displayed like that. Even though you can embed images and widgets in a Text object, I think it is not possible to have that layout.

Comment: I assumed that would be the case, but I found an alternate solution. thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the behavior you want with the text widget. You cannot wrap a paragraph of text around or to the side of an image.

If you're merely wanting to align a little bit of text with an image (versus trying to emulate the behavior of commercial word processors), put a text widget and the image as two separate widgets in a frame. Pack the image on the right and the text on the left.

Comment: I assumed that would be the case, but I found an alternate solution. thx anyway.